# Rosws error trying to overlay common_msgs

Tags: ros, rosws, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i just tried to setup my Fuerte workspace using rosws. This also includes an overlay of common_msgs and one package that depends on common_msgs. When I add the common_msgs stack to my workspace using "rosws merge" and try to build the package that depends on geometry_msgs, i get the following error when trying to rosmake:

```
[rosbuild] Building package morsetesting
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only morsetesting
  Package geometry_msgs was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `geometry_msgs.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'geometry_msgs' found
```

After removing the overlay of common_msgs (using "rosws remove"), i can build the package again... Is this a bug or am i missing something here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33371/rosws-error-trying-to-overlay-common_msgs/) by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-05-06**:
I should mention that for my project, an overlay of common_msgs does not make sense any more since the python code is now stored outside of the rospackage anyway, but still i´m interested in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `common_msgs` stack builds using catkin, not rosmake, now.

If you need to build it from source as an overlay, you will have to use the new tools.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-05-06**:
Tanks. So i cannot mix packages that are build by catkin with packages built by rosmake... Would you recommend to replace rosmake-builds completely by catkin?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-06**:
Not yet. Catkin building is not yet fully documented. I believe you can build and install something using catkin, then refer to the new version in other packages.